# how the callback function be triggered in the keras.callbacks.Callback class?

Tags: callback, keras

This a code sample as follows, the LoggingReporter class redefine the callback of the keras. As the model is trained, the callback function is runned. But i want to know where the function 'on_train_begin' triggered.

```python
class LoggingReporter(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
          ...
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
          ...


reporter = LoggingReporter()
r = model.fit(..., callbacks  = [reporter,])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's triggered in the training files which depends on whether you use `.fit`  or `.fit_generator`. [Here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/4e829712a2c6153d4cb0c34507fa3f5a7814a2a9/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L144) is the location for `on_epoch_begin` for `.fit' method.